# C Read Different Byte Size Data Binary File

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fread

I am trying to read the header of a binary file that is 10 bytes. The header structure is like so:

x - 4 bytes

y - 4 bytes

z - 2 bytes

I am trying to read the file with the following code. It works correctly for x & y, but not for z. I know the issue is that I read 4 bytes for all 3 data points, but z is only 2 bytes. How can I read z differently?

```
FILE *fileToRead = fopen("test.bin","rb");
uint32_t dataPoint;
int a = 0;
int x,y,z;
while(fread(&dataPoint,sizeof(dataPoint),1,fileToRead)==1){
    if(a == 0) {
        x = dataPoint;
    } else if(a == 1) {
        y = dataPoint;
    } else {
        z = dataPoint;
    }
    a++;
}
fclose(fileToRead);
```

Comment: Why don't you just call `fread` three times with the appropriate parameters? (You end up doing something very similar with the `while` loop, anyway.) A loop is not always a silver bullet.

Comment: ha... so simple. Should have thought of that. Thanks @DYZ !